# sending a method on nodejs with admin account

Tags: web3js, nodejs, private-key

I want to send a method from the owner's account to which I have the private key.
[image]

I tried adding the private key int he red rectangle but when I run it I get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the `send()` method incorrectly. Please read the [web3js official documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) in order to send a transaction to a smart contract and execute its method.

Seems like you want to sign a transaction using a hardcoded signer private key, rather than requesting a signature through a crypto wallet. In this case, follow this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/51744/119701).

Comment: I'm trying to send a method. The issue is when doing that `code` send({from:address}).then((err,result)=>

I receive an error saying that the acount is unknow. And I should call this from the owner's account which should be hooked to the server. Any ideas?